# Where can I define my custom form element render on Summary Page

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I build on my TYPO3 8.7 a custom form element with this tutorial https://gist.github.com/manuelselbach/dc63abd313694c594d480b163a5f3053

But on the Summary Page my custom form element renders wrong. Where can I set the FluidTemplate to renders right?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    :
    view {
        partialRootPaths {
            40 = EXT:your_custom_extension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        }
    }
    :
```

here you define the path to your partials. there probably also exist a path to the templates and the layouts. or you may need to add pathes for layouts and templates in the typoscript.

if you can identify in which file(s) your changes are needed, you can copy this file / these files to your local folders and add the changes.

Comment: Thank you, yes there I put my changed Files. The form shows right, on the first page. But on the Summary Page, it renders wrong. But I don't know the name or path for the Summary fluid file.

Comment: Typoscript can be configured in a lot of ways. you need to explore where the configure origins. first try the TSOB to see what is your current  TS on those pages. notice conditions. use the template analyzer to find all templates and extension templates.